# Problems with updating asp .net (vb) web app

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Hi i just update an old webapp and now i have this error

> Error 10  Type 'System.Web.Security.MembershipUser' in assembly
>   'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' has been forwarded to assembly
>   'System.Web.ApplicationServices'. Either a reference to
>   'System.Web.ApplicationServices' is missing from your project or the
>   type 'System.Web.Security.MembershipUser' is missing from assembly
>   'System.Web.ApplicationServices'. E:\PC\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\TIVENCA\Fuente\Tivenca
>   10-12-2008\Mega.TimeCard.Web\Cargar\Cargar.aspx.vb    89  27  E:...\Mega.TimeCard.Web\

Here is the line

```
Dim mu As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser(Profile.UserName)
```

Here is the references

[image: Errors]

And here are the lots of errors

[image: References]

And finally my web.config file (Download txt)

https://mega.co.nz/#!WkZSCQ4I!NM-JjVgRPS6eTVy6bYO_RmdSLY4Hxp3H_TkWVlG9mlI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a lot of trying to solve, i finally did with it

I change on web.config all the versions from 3.5 to 4.0 and solved this error

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**

Based on that screen shot you should remove the 3.5 and 1.0.61025.0 versions for the system.web.extensions assembly.  Only the 4.0 reference should be there.  The others are confusing it as you can only reference 1 version of an assembly in your project.

---

Sounds like you ran into one of the .net 4 breaking changes:

[Breaking Changes](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770156)

The work around is to add the System.Web.ApplicationServices assembly to your project.  That should have happened during the conversion.. depending on what you did to convert it.

Comment: I added the reference, still nothing, updated from 2008 to 2010 vb (visual studio)

Comment: yes i did, i added the reference System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll still gives the same error, i think i have to change the code line @Chris Lively